# T-SQL - Loss of float precision when using procedures

Tags: t-sql

I have been trying to create a T-SQL procedure where I sum all of the family's monthly income into a variable `@prihodki` and at the same time, I sum all of the family's monthly expense into a variable `@odhodki`. Printing a variable inside this procedure outputs the correct answer, however when I try to execute the procedure and store the returned value into a variable, the precision gets lost.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE izracunajPromet_TaMesec
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @prihodki float, @odhodki float;

        SELECT @prihodki = SUM(t.Vrednost) 
        FROM Transakcija t 
        WHERE YEAR(t.Datum) = YEAR(current_timestamp) 
          AND MONTH(t.Datum) = MONTH(current_timestamp) 
          AND t.ID_Družine = 1 
          AND t.Vrednost >= 0;

        SELECT @odhodki = SUM(t.Vrednost) 
        FROM Transakcija t 
        WHERE YEAR(t.Datum) = YEAR(current_timestamp) 
          AND MONTH(t.Datum) = MONTH(current_timestamp) 
          AND t.ID_Družine = 1 
          AND t.Vrednost <= 0;

        IF (@prihodki IS NOT NULL AND @odhodki IS NOT NULL)
            RETURN CAST((@prihodki + @odhodki) AS NUMERIC(10, 2));
        ELSE IF (@prihodki IS NOT NULL AND @odhodki IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            PRINT @prihodki;
            RETURN CAST(@prihodki AS float);
        END
        ELSE 
            RETURN CAST(@odhodki AS NUMERIC(10, 2));
    END

    RETURN 0;
go

DECLARE @rezultat float;

EXEC @rezultat = izracunajPromet_TaMesec;

PRINT @rezultat;
```

The procedure prints out a value `67.73`, while the execution and storage method returns a value of `67`.

I have already tried casting and converting, but none of these solutions worked.

NOTE: Focus on ELSE IF part, because that's where I have been getting this precision loss and I assume that once this is solved, I will be able to update IF and ELSE parts too.

Comment: Aside: A best practice when using "now" across multiple statements is to save it in a variable and use that value as needed. The two `select` statements in your code may happen to execute in different months leading to confusing results that are difficult to recreate.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [Returning Data Using a Return Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15#returning-data-using-a-return-code):

> A procedure can return an integer value called a return code to
>   indicate the execution status of a procedure.

Review the rest of the document (Return Data from a Stored Procedure) for ways to return non-integer data.

---

As for improving the code, there are several opportunities. It seems more natural to make this a user-defined function, but I have kept the stored procedure and added an `output` parameter for the result. It isn't clear why the values are being summed separately based on their signs and then added together when a simple sum would produce the same result. (The only benefit is an errant `print` statement if there are no non-positive values.) Note that the `where` condition has been made [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) so that an index can be used to improve performance.

```
create procedure izracunajPromet_TaMesec
  @Result as Numeric(10,2) output
  as
  begin

  set nocount on

  declare @prihodki as Numeric(10,2), @odhodki as Numeric(10,2);

  -- Get the current date/time.
  declare @Now as DateTime = Current_Timestamp;
  -- Calculate the first date of the current month.
  declare @MonthStart as Date = DateAdd( day, 1 - Day( @Now ), @Now );
  -- Calculate the first date of the next month.
  declare @NextMonthStart as Date = DateAdd( month, 1, @MonthStart );

  select
    -- Use conditional aggregation to get both sums from a single pass through the data.
    @prihodki = sum( case when Vrednost >= 0 then Vrednost end ),
    @odhodki = sum( case when Vrednost <= 0 then Vrednost end ) 
    from Transakcija
    where
      -- Filter the date(time) using a half-open interval so that an index can be used.
      @MonthStart <= Datum and Datum < @NextMonthStart and
      ID_Družine = 1;

    -- If either value is   NULL   then substitute   0.0   and return the result.
    set @Result = Coalesce( @prihodki, 0.0 ) + Coalesce( @odhodki, 0.0 );

    return;

  end;
```

Sample usage:

```
declare @MyResult as Numeric(10,2);
execute izracunajPromet_TaMesec @Result = @MyResult output;
select @MyResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for a while, I finally came up with an idea to return the value in form of a table and extract the value from it. This may or may not be the perfect solution, but it works. I am open to optimizations.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE izracunajPromet_TaMesec
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @result TABLE (Rezultat float);
        DECLARE @prihodki float, @odhodki float;

        SELECT @prihodki = SUM(t.Vrednost) 
        FROM Transakcija t 
        WHERE YEAR(t.Datum) = YEAR(current_timestamp) 
          AND MONTH(t.Datum) = MONTH(current_timestamp) 
          AND t.ID_Družine = 1 
          AND t.Vrednost >= 0;

        SELECT @odhodki = SUM(t.Vrednost) 
        FROM Transakcija t 
        WHERE YEAR(t.Datum) = YEAR(current_timestamp) 
          AND MONTH(t.Datum) = MONTH(current_timestamp) 
          AND t.ID_Družine = 1 
          AND t.Vrednost <= 0;

        IF @prihodki IS NULL
            SET @prihodki = 0;
        IF @odhodki IS NULL
            SET @odhodki = 0;

        INSERT INTO @result VALUES (@prihodki + @odhodki);
        SELECT * FROM @result;
    END

    RETURN 0;
go

DECLARE @result TABLE (Rezultat float);
DECLARE @numres float;
INSERT @result exec izracunajPromet_TaMesec;
SELECT @numres = Rezultat FROM @result;
PRINT @numres;
```

Comment: I took the liberty of amending my answer to suggest some optimizations.