# Setting a variable using a stored procedure without printing an output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure as follows which returns a value:

```
DECLARE @outputValue decimal(18,10)
set @outputValue = (
select TOP 1 TotalUsageFactor as '801 UNR Usage Factor'
from MarketMessage as a
inner join messagetype591 as b on a.MarketMessageID = b.MarketMessageID
inner join AdditionalAggregationInformation as c on b.MessageType591ID = c.MessageType591ID
inner join AdditionalAggregationData as d on c.AdditionalAggregationInformationID = d.AdditionalAggregationInformationID
where SettlementRunIndicator = 20
and LoadProfileCode = 801
and TimeOfUse = 'UNR'
order by SettlementDate desc)
RETURN @outputValue
```

Despite this being a decimal value I seem to always be only able to return an int, this is used within another parent stored procedure and is called as follows:

```
DECLARE @UsageFactor801UNR decimal(18,10)
EXEC @UsageFactor801UNR = GetLatestUsageFactor801UNR
```

If I do it this way there is no output value being returned and at the end of the query I am being returned the final table of data as expected. If I however change the code to the following:

```
select TOP 1 TotalUsageFactor as '801 UNR Usage Factor'
from MarketMessage as a
inner join messagetype591 as b on a.MarketMessageID = b.MarketMessageID
inner join AdditionalAggregationInformation as c on b.MessageType591ID = c.MessageType591ID
inner join AdditionalAggregationData as d on c.AdditionalAggregationInformationID = d.AdditionalAggregationInformationID
where SettlementRunIndicator = 20
and LoadProfileCode = 801
and TimeOfUse = 'UNR'
order by SettlementDate desc
RETURN
```

I am now able to retrieve the correct decimal value but in my parent query I am returning these values before returning the table of information that I actually require, how can I have it so that I am able to return a decimal value from the function with no output or have it so that there is no return from the execution of the query within the parent

Comment: Suggested reading: [Return Data from a Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15). The [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement only returns an `int`, typically used for a completion status. Or see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61572492/t-sql-loss-of-float-precision-when-using-procedures/61574846#61574846) answer.

Comment: If you want to "return" a scalar value, use an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: @Larnu I have tried to use the output paramater but it always rounds to an int

Comment: @Seán-Pól according to the code you have posted you have tried to use the stored procedure's `RETURN STATUS`, which is always an `INT`. Have a read through the [CREATE PROCEDURE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql) documentation, especially where it says, "_OUT | OUTPUT Indicates that the parameter is an output parameter. Use OUTPUT parameters to return values to the caller of the procedure._"